# How can I tidy this data set in r studio step by step?

Tags: r, rstudio, tidyr

I am looking to tidy a data set using R Studio. I was wondering how I can clean this data set step by step.
The data look like the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvBWI.png)

but I want them to look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvAOQ.png)

Any idea what the r code I need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you need.

```
    #Creating the dataframe
country=c("Aghanistan","Aghanistan","Aghanistan","Brazil","Brazil","Brazil","China","China","China")
    Indicator=c("ind1","ind2","ind3","ind1","ind2","ind3","ind1","ind2","ind3")
    `1999`=c(745,19987071,0.373,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
    `2000`=c(2666,20595360,1.29,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
    df<-as.data.frame(cbind(country,Indicator,`1999`,`2000`))

    library(tidyr)
    df.long<-gather(df,Year,measurement,`1999`:`2000`,factor_key = T)#get the years right
    df.final<-spread(df.long,Indicator,measurement)#reformat for final
    df.final#scope the result
```